# Calculating distances based off a list of lists

Tags: python

So I have recently started programming in Python and I'm still trying to think in the latter.
I have a small project for University where I have 6 problems based on a list of lists. My teacher calls it an array. I dont know if this is the right place to ask for some help, but here I go:
I've got the first two alright but then I got stuck.

First of all, I had to calculate the Euclidean distance between two points:
Each 'cell' of the list of lists represents a square with 20m on the side, which represents a certain altitude.

```
Altitude = [ [206,205,204,190,208],
             [190,194,206,197,203], 
             [196,196,205,201,193], 
             [194,199,199,206,205], 
             [192,196,195,201,193], 
             [194,199,200,200,205],
             [196,196,195,200,193] ]

from numpy import sqrt
def distance(altitude, side, p1, p2):
    r1 = p1[0]
    r2 = p2[0]
    c1 = p1[1]
    c2 = p2[1]
    w = side
    a1 = altitudes [p1[0]][p1[1]]
    a2= altitudes [p2[0]][p2[1]]
    d =sqrt((w*(r1 - r2))**2+ (w*(c1-c2))**2 + (a1-a2)**2)
    return d
```

Then I had to create a function to calculate the distance when it was given a certain path of 'cells':

```
def traveled_distance (altitude, side, path):
    dist = 0
    for v in range(len(path)-1):
            dist = dist + distance(altitude, side, path[v], path[v+1])
    return dist
```

This is where I started getting stuck.
The next exercise consists in calculating the 'cell' in which the path will stop when travelling north, from a starting point. 
Note that one can only travel to a cell with higher value in altitude.

I tried  a 'for loop' using if and elif, but couldn't write a working code.

```
def climb_north (altitude, start_point):
    alt_north = 0
    for a in altitude (...)
```

---

The 4th part of the work consists in implementing a function called:

```
def neighbours(altitude, cell):
```

which returns a list of tuples with the coordinates (row and column) of neighbor cells of the variable --- cell ---which is also a tuple.
The neighbour cells are located S, N, W, E, NE, NW, SW and SE.

---

The 5th problem is about the neighbour cell with the higher altitude value.
The function should be called:

```
def higher_neighbour(altitude, cell):
```

If the cell has a bigger value than its neighbours it should return its own coordinates;
If the cell has more than one neighbour with the same higher altitude, it can return any of those coordinates.

---

In the last exercise we are told to write the code of a function

```
def climb_higher (altitude, cell)
```

where given a certain 'cell' it returns a list of tuples with the row and column of each visited point, so that each cell moves to a neighbouring cell with a higher altitude, until it reaches a peak, where that cell is the highest between its neighbours

Comment: I know its a long question, but I'e been looking at this for so long that I'm kind of desperate.

Comment: You have provided some context but your question isn't very clear. Please be more specific.

Comment: What can I specify better? I tried explaining it properly. Which topic was unclear?

Comment: You have listed 6 problems in your university project. Which problem(s) do you need help with?

Comment: The 1st and 2nd problems are solved. I got stuck on the third one

Comment: I've seen some videos on loops and cycles and I just can't think in that specific way, I get easily confused, while for others it is really intuitive....

Comment: Can you explain what exactly "travelling north"  means? I suppose that at a certain point,  somehow, you have no more valid moves available and that's the stop point, but I feel I miss something

Comment: when I say travelling north I mean going up on the list of lists. from a cell to the one on top.